# Mutiny reactive - persist to DB if upstream is not null

Tags: reactive-programming, quarkus, quarkus-panache, mutiny

I working on a Quarkus + MongoDB Reactive+ Mutiny application. I have a ***Person*** object and ***Event*** Object. I am creating a new event for a person. My uri looks like this

> POST /person/{personId}/event

I need to first check if the person exists in MongoDB. If the person exists then save event. If person does not exist then create a Error Status and return. I am tried everything but I am stuck and getting error that required return type is Uni but required type is Uni. I tried with ***transformToUni*** as well but it did not work. Also tried few other ways like ***onItemOrFailure()*** etc. but nothing seems to work.
[image]

Here's the full Code.

```
public class EventResource {

    @Inject
    EventRepository eventRepository;

    @Inject
    PersonRepository personRepository;

    @POST
    @Path("/{person_id}/event")
    public Uni<Response> create(Event event, @PathParam("person_id") String personId){
        //Check if personId exist.
        Uni<Person> uniPerson = personRepository.getPersonById(personId);

        //THIS WORKS BUT ON FAILURE IS TREATED WHEN ERROR IS RAISED FOR EeventRepository.craete() and not if person is not found.
         /*return uniPerson.onItem().ifNotNull()
                                    .transformToUni(pid -> eventRepository.create(event, pid.getId()))
                                    .onItem().transform(e -> Response.ok().entity(e).build())

                .onFailure()
                .recoverWithItem(f-> {
                    AStatus status =  createErrorStatus(f.getMessage());
                    return Response.serverError().entity(status).build();
                });
*/
        Uni<Response> eventResp = uniPerson.onItem().transform(person -> {
                                                        if(person==null)
                                                            return Response.serverError().build();
                                                        else{
                                                          return    eventRepository.create(event, person.getId())
                                                                  .onItem().transform(event1 -> Response.ok(event1).build());

                                                        }


                                                    });

        return eventResp;


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [mutiny ifNull](https://smallrye.io/smallrye-mutiny/guides/handling-null):

```
    @POST
    @Path("/{person_id}/event")
    public Uni<Response> create(Event event, @PathParam("person_id") String personId){
         return personRepository
                 .getPersonById(personId)
                 .onItem().ifNotNull().transformToUni(person -> createEvent(event, person))
                 .onItem().ifNull().continueWith(this::personNotFound)
                 // This onFailure will catch all the errors
                 .onFailure()
                    .recoverWithItem(f-> {
                         AStatus status =  createErrorStatus(f.getMessage());
                         return Response.serverError().entity(status).build();
                    });
    }


    private Uni<Response> createEvent(Event event, Person person) {
        return eventRepository
            .create(event, person.getId())
            .map( e -> Response.ok().entity(e).status(CREATED).build())
    }

    private Response personNotFound() {
        return Response.serverError().build();
    }
```

The error you are seeing is because when the item is not null, you are returning a `Uni<Uni<Response>>`. This is one way to fix it:

```
Uni<Response> eventResp = uniPerson
    .chain(person -> {
        if (person==null)
            return Uni.createFrom().item(Response.serverError().build());
        else {
            return eventRepository
                .create(event, person.getId())
                .map(event1 -> Response.ok(event1).build());
        }
    });
```

I'm using `map` and `chain` because they are shorter, but you can replace them with `onItem().transform(...)` and `onItem().transformToUni(...)`.